# Android Auto isn't automatically binding to MediaBrowserService or MediaLibraryService

Tags: android, exoplayer, android-auto, android-media3

I'm trying to add Android Auto capability to my existing app. It's a messaging app, but some messages have an audio attachment. So far, I was successfully able to create a `CarAppService` to display the messages themselves, but I can't seem to be able to get the audio playback to connect to the Android Auto (so that it's tied to a a media session and showing playback controls in the Android Auto dashboard).

I followed the instructions [here](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/media#terms-concepts), and I also tried using the new Media3 library (using sample code [here](https://github.com/androidx/media/tree/main/demos/session)), but neither one seems to activate the `MediaBrowserService` (or `MediaLibraryService` in case of Media3).

I have the foreground service permission and the browser service declared in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.car.notification.SmallIcon"
           android:resource="@drawable/ic_auto_icon" />

        <service
            android:name=".auto.MediaService"
            android:foregroundServiceType="mediaPlayback"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="androidx.media3.session.MediaSessionService"/>
                <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

and I have the `MediaLibraryService` all set with creating a media session, using my existing `ExoPlayer` instance, and being initialized with the proper `MediaLibrarySession.Callback`. But the `onCreate()' method of the MediaLibraryService (or MediaBrowserService) never gets called.

What am I missing? Is there something that I need to do in the car app itself to make it bind to the media browser service?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out what was happening, and the problem is basically due to almost complete lack of documentation for Android Auto. As I said in my OP, I have two different services set up: `CarAppService` and `MediaBrowserService`. Because of that, my app gets shown twice in AA (2 icons that launch 2 completely different versions of the app). So, each service gets treated like a completely separate app. And once I realized that, I created different icons and labels for each service in the Manifest, so at least now I'm able to differentiate them.

When launching the `MediaBrowserService`, it acts as expected - it automatically binds to the service, and allows the user to browse through the media files (as if it were just a simple media player app).

But even launching the other one (which is the one I was originally posting about), I had to manually create a media browser client, and have it bind to the media browser service using `MediaBrowserCompat`.

I also figured out a way to have the `MediaBrowserService` icon hidden, but still retain the functionality to use it for before payback in the background. That can be done by removing the `<intent-filter>` component of that service from the Manifest. The only problem with doing it that way is that we also lose Android Auto's payback controls, so the media plays without a problem, but it would have to be controlled from the CarAppService, which eliminates the option of controlling it in the background.